# Can "pinky" a verb as in "do you pinky swear"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, idioms, phrase-choice

In Urban dictionary (a slang dictionary)

They say

> [pinky swear](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pinky%20swear)
>
> An eternally binding act of hooking pinky fingers together in an
> attempt to seal the deal of a promise that has been made.
>
> I promise to never do that again!
>
> Do you pinky swear?

[In Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinky_swear), they also say

> **To pinky swear**, or to make a pinky promise, is a traditional gesture
> most commonly practiced amongst children involving the locking of the
> pinkies of two people to signify that a promise has been made

For example, each time my daughter wants to watch TV, she and I often agree that I allow her to watch TV for 10 minutes only.

Is it correct for me to say to her "**do we pinky swear?**" or "**do we have a pinky swear?**" before we hook our little fingers together as an action of agreement?

Comment: I've seen the action, but not heard the phrase because we call it the 'little finger' in British English.

Comment: If "pinky swearing" is understood by your daughter then maybe you should ask "Shall we pinky swear?" or perhaps "We must {or need to} pinky swear ...". On the other hand, any kind of swearing sounds excessive for ten minutes of TV.

Comment: I believe the most natural phrasing would simply be something like "Just 10 minutes, OK...pinky swear?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“to pinky swear” is a phrasal verb, and I would analyze it as “pinky” being an adverb since it specifies how we swear (the action).

The noun form would be “a pinky promise”, with “pinky” being a noun adjunct that specifies what form of promise.